# php mysql foreach echos wrong

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have two tables in db: item table (goods1) and order table (kB). In kB each order item equals a single row meaning an order of 2 items = 2 rows with the same bill number in the appropriate column. IU want to group the ordered items to each bill number
I got the following:

```
 <?
 ...

 $sql = $conn->query("
 SELECT 
 kB.BillNum AS B, goods1.*, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(goods1.ArtName) AS bestArts, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(goods1.ArtNrAttach) AS ArtNrAttachs, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(kB.Menge) AS Menges,
 FROM 
 kB, goods1 
 WHERE kB.bestArt = goods1.id 
 AND kB.ordDate LIKE '%$datum_seek%' 
 GROUP BY kB.BillNum");

 if(mysqli_error($conn)){ echo " ERROR";}
 ELSE IF(!mysqli_error($conn)){


 echo'<table colspan="6" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <tr>
      <th colspan="1">bill number</th>
      <th colspan="1">item</th>
      <th colspan="1">item nummer</th>
      </tr>';

 while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {

 $bestArts     = split(",",$row["bestArts"]);
 $ArtNrAttachs = split(",",$row["ArtNrAttachs"]);
 $Menges       = split(",",$row["Menges"]);

 echo '<tr><td style="background-color:lightblue;">'. $row["B"].'</td>';
 ?>
 <td><?php echo $bestArts[0]; array_shift($bestArts); ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $ArtNrAttachs[0]; array_shift($ArtNrAttachs); ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $Menges[0]; array_shift($Menges); ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>

 <?php 
    foreach($bestArts as $bestArt):
      echo '<td>' . $bestArt .'</td>';
      endforeach;

    foreach($ArtNrAttachs as $ArtNrAttach):
      echo '<td>' . $ArtNrAttach .'</td>';
      endforeach;

    foreach($Menges as $Menge): 
      echo '<td>' . $Menge .'</td>';
      endforeach;

    ...
```

This prints all right:

```
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
```

but if I have more than 2 lines for each 'B'(items for 1 order) then it prints like this:

```
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtName |ArtNr | ArtNr | Menge | Menge |
```

The expected output:

```
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
```

I tried, but I cannot find a solution to this. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: where do you print <tr> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expected output is:

```
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
| B | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
    | ArtName | ArtNr | Menge |
```

You could change your code to: (assuming `$bestArts`, `$bestArts`, `$ArtNrAttachs` have the same size)

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($bestArts); $i++) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $bestArts[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ArtNrAttachs[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Menges[$i];?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

And remove the foreach's.

---

Proposing minimal change, but sure you need to rethink about your code structure.

Comment: @ Berriel your suggestion is not  printing the first line of each 'B'. if there are 2 lines then it prints 1 , if there are 3 it prints 2.....

Comment: @ceyrslan sry, `array_shift` was still there, try the updated version

Comment: still no change, still 2 instead of three and 1 instead of 2 only now i receive each time for  the last displayed lines **Notice: Undefined offset: 1**